# Nginx proxy_pass with $remote_addr

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I'm trying to include $remote_addr or $http_remote_addr on my proxy_pass without success.

The rewrite rule works

```
location ^~ /freegeoip/ {  
  rewrite ^ http://freegeoip.net/json/$remote_addr last;
}
```

The proxy_pass without the $remote_addr works, but freegeoip does not read the x-Real-IP

```
location ^~ /freegeoip/ {
  proxy_pass http://freegeoip.net/json/;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

Then, I'm adding the ip to the end of the request, like this:

```
location ^~ /freegeoip/ {
  proxy_pass http://freegeoip.net/json/$remote_addr;
}
```

but nginx report this error: no resolver defined to resolve freegeoip.net

Comment: does the error occur when you restart nginx, or when an http request hits the location block?

Comment: When I request the url

Answer (score 204, accepted):

If the `proxy_pass` statement has no variables in it, then it will use the "gethostbyaddr" system call during start-up or reload and will cache that value permanently.

if there are any variables, such as using either of the following:

```
set $originaddr http://origin.example.com;
proxy_pass $originaddr;
# or even
proxy_pass http://origin.example.com$request_uri;
```

Then nginx will use a built-in resolver, and the "resolver" directive *must* be present. "resolver" is probably a misnomer; think of it as "what DNS server will the built-in resolver use". Since nginx 1.1.9 the built-in resolver will honour DNS TTL values. Before then it used a fixed value of 5 minutes.

Comment: This is a _much_ more useful and informative answer. Thank you.

Comment: The key being any variable present in the proxy_pass value, thanks for the right answer and explanation.

Comment: Some reference?

Comment: Fun fact: docker container's default nameserver is at `127.0.0.11`, see `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: What am I supposed to set the resolver to if it is running kubernetes?  There is no resolv.conf file.

Comment: I've been trying for a while to find out why the `resolver` was needed. Thanks!

Comment: FYI -- when running in docker compose, based on the information in this answer/comment thread, we used:
resolver 127.0.0.11;

This allowed nginx to find the server that we needed. Super helpful. Thank you.

Comment: This also explains why [resolver kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local;](https://serverfault.com/a/1035780) works on Kubernetes.

Answer (score 95):

It seems a bit strange that nginx is failing to resolve the domain name at runtime rather than at configuration time (since the domain name is hard coded). Adding a `resolver` declaration to the location block usually fixes dns issues experienced at runtime. So your location block might look like:

```
location ^~ /freegeoip/ {
  #use google as dns
  resolver 8.8.8.8;
  proxy_pass http://freegeoip.net/json/$remote_addr;
}
```

This solution is based on an article I read a while back - [Proxy pass and resolver](http://www.nginx-discovery.com/2011/05/day-51-proxypass-and-resolver.html). Would be worth a read.

Comment: Do **NOT** use a publicly accessible DNS server such as `8.8.8.8`. [To prevent DNS spoofing, it is recommended configuring DNS servers in a properly secured trusted local network.](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it cover other cases, like args, remote_addr, etc

Comment: This is still valid with latest stable nginx/1.10.3. So `resolver` directive is required in conjunction with `proxy_pass` dynamic directive e.g. `proxy_pass http://$host;`. While this one works w/o resolver:  ```server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myurl.com;
    location / {return 303 https://$host$request_uri;}
}
```

Comment: In my case (Google Cloud), I used the internal nameserver, 169.254.169.254, to resolve other instances in my tenant by hostname.

Answer (score 17):

If anyone is stll experiencing trouble, *for me it helped* to move the proxy_pass host to a seperate upstream, so I come up with something like this

```
upstream backend-server {
  server backend.service.consul;
}

server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  frontend.test.me;

  location ~/api(.*)$  {
    proxy_pass http://backend-server$1;
  }
  location / {
    # this works mystically! backend doesn't...
    proxy_pass http://frontend.service.consul/;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the easier answer if your proxied URI does not change, and no need to add additional  resolver step!

Answer (score 2):

Another way is that you can provide your host `ip` address and `port` number instead of host `URL` in `proxy_pass` like below:

**Your Code:**
`proxy_pass http://freegeoip.net/json/;`

**Updated Code**
`proxy_pass http://10.45.45.10:2290/json/;`

Comment: This worked for me, was trying to proxy back to some Docker intstances on localhost, but localhost didn't work (couldn't be resolved for whatever reason) but 127.0.0.1 worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

So you want this to work:

```
location ^~ /freegeoip/ {
  proxy_pass http://freegeoip.net/json/$remote_addr;
}
```

but as [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22259088/1024811) by Chris Cogdon, it fails because at run-time, nginx does not have the domain name resolved, and so `proxy_pass` requires a resolver (see also, [proxy_pass docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)).

Something that seems to work (though may be a hack!) is to do something that triggers nginx to resolve the domain name at start-up and cache this.

So, change the config to include a location (for the same host) without any variables (as well as your location *with* variables):

```
location = /freegeoip/this-location-is-just-a-hack {
  # A dummy location. Use any path, but keep the hostname.
  proxy_pass http://freegeoip.net/this-path-need-not-exist;
}

location ^~ /freegeoip/ {
  proxy_pass http://freegeoip.net/json/$remote_addr;
}
```

The host will now be resolved at start-up (and its cached value will be used in the second location at run-time). You can verify this start-up resolution behavior by changing hostname (`freegeoip.net`) to something that doesn't exist, and when you run `nginx -t` or `nginx -s reload` you'll have an emergency error (`[emerg] host not found in upstream`). And of course you can verify that the cached value is used at run-time by leaving out any `resolver`, hitting your `location` block, and observing no errors in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

You could also mention your nginx `server port` in the `proxy_pass uri`. This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use dig / nslookup to make sure this is still nginx issue.
In my case the issue was that one of dns server between my nginx and root dns was not respecting TTL values that are as small as 1 second.

[Nginx does not re-resolve DNS names in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67439712/nginx-does-not-re-resolve-dns-names-in-docker/70654684#70654684)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is dealing with this issue, its important to set the proxy header after the proxy_pass and then this should resolve the issue:

```
        proxy_pass http://backend-server;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $host;
```