# Nginx variables ignore case

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-config, service-discovery

I'm setting up Nginx using Docker's service discovery. My service name is `webAdmin`.

Relevant section of the current Nginx config reads

```
resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=10s;  # Docker DNS server
if (!-f $request_filename) {
    set $upstream_admin_server webAdmin:8000;
    proxy_pass http://$upstream_admin_server;
    break;
}
```

When visiting the appropriate server, Nginx returns a 404. The logs reveal that Nginx is attempting to resolve a lower case version of my service name.

```
2019/08/26 21:53:46 [error] 3756#3756: *1569 webadmin could not be resolved (3: Host not found), client: 10.0.0.29, server: admin.mysite.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "admin.mysite.com"
```

When I avoid using a variable the config reads

```
resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=10s;  # Docker DNS server
if (!-f $request_filename) {
    proxy_pass http://webAdmin:8000;
    break;
}
```

Nginx is then able to resolve the service name and correctly route my request.

I attempted to use quotes, single and double but neither seem to have any effect. The Nginx docs for `set` don't seem to offer any clues.

Why is my variable being converted to lower case?

Comment: which base image you are using and nginx version?

Comment: The base docker image is pulled from `nginx:1.15.9`. Which uses Nginx version 1.15.12.

Comment: You can try my posted image and it will definitely resolve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Nginx attempts to resolve a name it actually forces the name to lower case. [Source can be found here](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/8e2949e56a13405a157e05b21aa4c4a5fa468335/src/core/ngx_resolver.c#L594).

I assume this decision was made with the knowledge that DNS names are supposed to be "case insensitive". But it results in inconsistent behavior between an explicitly declared `resolver` and the default `resolver`.

For now it seems that the best option is to avoid the use of capitalization in service names. (ie. `webAdmin` -> `web_admin`)

Thanks to Adiii for the guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine with me using `nginx:alpine`. I test it using the below configuration and changing the value for `LocalhOst`.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
location / {
       set $upstream_admin_server LocalhOst:80;
       proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
       proxy_pass         http://$upstream_admin_server/index.html;

 }
location /index.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

You can test it below command.

```
docker run --rm --name my-custom-nginx-container -p 80:80 -v $PWD/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf -it nginx:alpine
```

[image]

Comment: While doing some more digging, I noticed that I can achieve the same results as you when I comment out my resolver. `no resolver defined to resolve webAdmin`. Perhaps the resolver is doing the coercion?

Comment: Yes maybe, I thought its comment. :D

Comment: you do not need to define Docker DNS server

Comment: Could you expand on not needing to define the Docker DNS server? I was under the impression that if I used a variable in the `proxy_pass` statement, it was [necessary to define a resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22259088/7129097). I could get away with not using a variable but that would require me to reload Nginx any time I added or removed a service.